# How to call a function stored in a Python class instance variable

Tags: python, class, instance-variables, function-parameter

I'm passing a function as a parameter to a class constructor. The constructor stores it in an instance variable, and other class methods want to call it.

```
class ComboList(list) :
    def __init__(self,a,b,kg) :
        list.__init__(self)
        self.__kg = kg
        # More stuff follows
```

When I try to call the function in another method, for example:

```
x = self.__kg('a')
```

I get "{AttributeError}'' object has no attribute '__kg'."

When I evaluate the function call in my IDE's Evaluate Expression window, I get the same thing. But when I evaluate the instance variable itself ("self.__kg"), I get:

```
result = {function} <function <lambda> at 0x0000000002ED5C18>
```

...so it appears that the attribute __kg *is* defined.

What is going wrong?

I can call the function by referencing the parameter -- no problem.

```
kg(a')
```

I can also assign the parameter's value to a method variable and call the variable -- no problem.

```
_kag = kg
_kag('a')
```

It's only the reference to the instance variable that doesn't work.

Comment: This is [**name mangling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_Python) - try `_ComboList__kg`. Or just ditch the double underscores.

Comment: Can you please update the code where you are creating object of `ComboList` and calling the kg function?

Comment: jonrsharpe, that makes sense but it's surprising. I know name mangling is supposed to make variables hard to get by accident outside the scope object where they're defined. I didn't expect it to make the hard to get on purpose WITHIN the scope object. @Anand, it's not clear what kind of update you mean. The code hasn't changed in any relevant way. If this is still want, please clarify and I'll try to accommodate you.

Comment: I mean i tried your simplified approach in python 3.3, and it does not give me any error, can you update atleast the complete method , where you are doing `x = self.__kg('a')`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a variable has a double underscore in a class, Python will invoke name mangling (see the [Python documentation on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)). Using double underscores is pretty much only to avoid name clashes with subclasses or to make a variable 'really private'. (See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) for more style suggestions).

If you want other inherited subclasses to use your private variable, you can either use one single underscore (`_kg`) or use the `@property` decorator.

Check out this really dumb example:

```
class ComboList(list) :
    def __init__(self,a,b,kg) :
        list.__init__(self)
        self.__kg = kg
        # More stuff follows

    @property
    def kg(self):
        return(self.__kg)

my_list = ComboList(1,2,'This will be printed')
print(my_list.kg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use double underscore, which makes python do some magic and append classname to variable names (called name mangling). Just use single underscore instead of double.